# Pass Array in MongoDB MapReduce scope

Tags: javascript, node.js, mongodb, mapreduce, mongoose

I'm working on a a MapReduce execution on my Node.js + Express.js server.

I'm using Mongoose as ODM, and I need to pass a key-value array named `_affinities` into the `map` function global scope. To do this, I'm currently passing the array inside the `o.scope` object:

```
var o = {}; // Object sent to Mongoose as options

// Scope to pass affinities
o.scope = {
    affs : _affinities,
    test : 'test'
}
```

However, while using those values in `o.map`, it says `affs` is an empty array. However, if I try to log `test`, it shows the correct value.

```
// Note: this is just a test, I don't need to pass affs & test as the key.
o.map = function() {
    emit({ 
       a : affs, 
       test : test,
       id : this._id 
    }, this.score);
}
```

I have only one finalize function (for testing), without a `reduce` one.

```
o.finalize = function (k, v) 
{
    return v;
}

MyModel.mapReduce(o, callback);
```

Am I doing something wrong? Is not supported by MongoDB passing arrays?

Comment: One idea: at the time of the call to `MyModel.mapReduce` is the array `_affinities` still set with the correct value? A reference to the array `_affinities` is stored in your `o.scope` object, not a copy.

Comment: I was so stupid not thinking about this, thanks so much!